# Java, как заменить произвольный элемент массива на символ ".."

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив `String[] term`, сделан из массива `int[] progression` с помощью `Arrays.toString`.
В массиве `term` мне нужно заменить рандомный элемент (определяется каждый раз заново переменной `int swap = random.nextInt(1, 10);`) на две точки `".."`

Я пытаюсь это явно перезаписать `term[swap] = "..";`

IDEA выдает ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 1

Не понимаю, в чём дело.  Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Приведите [mcve], а не отрывки в вашем пересказе

Comment: написано что с вашим рандомом вы выходите за рамки массива. Для начала попробуйте заменить конкретный потом следите чтоб ваш рандом не выходил за пределы массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.toString` преобразует в строку *весь массив `int[]`*, то есть для примера массив `term` будет содержать только один элемент-строку `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"` для входного массива из 4 элементов `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Чтобы преобразовать входной массив целых чисел в массив соответствующих строк, можно использовать Stream API (для краткости):

```java
int[] progression = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(progression));

String[] term = Arrays.stream(progression)
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .toArray(String[]::new);

Random random = new Random();
// теперь можно менять на многоточие некоторый элемент
term[random.nextInt(term.length)] = "...";
// и проверять результат при помощи Arrays.toString
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(term));
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, ..., 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Nowhere Man, огромное спасибо вам, очень помогли мне! Хорошего дня)